# Is WebSocket onMessage atomic?

Tags: websocket

I mean, is onMessage method would be triggered exactly once per atomic message from server, or:

1. Whether the message is short, 2 or more message might only trigger onMessage only once with one concatenated message, so we have to split the message manually?
2. Whether the message is long there would be multiple onMessage triggered with partial message each one so we have to concat the message manually?

I'm using C# and javascript for client side (2 product) and golang for server side

Answer (score 0):

All the messages are events technically, you can only read the data from them. You can also control buffer size for both write and read operations, but I think that if the message reaches those limits it wouldn't be separated